# Grails: Don't Run Filters on a Forward (without using flash variables)

Tags: grails, filter, forward

I'm writing a plugin that keeps track of the pages that a user has visited in an application (for the purpose of a back button).  It does this by having a filter that runs for every controller/action and keeps a list of visited pages.  Everything is working great, except that when used in applications that use forwards, the plugin records two entries for the one page since Grails filters run on every request, even when that request is just a forward (ie: internal redirect).

Since this is a plugin (that has to be application agnostic) I can't simply set a flash variable whenever a forward is used to check if a forward has occurred.  Is there any way to determine if a forward has occurred in a filter?  I'm exploring the different values in the request variable and how they differ between a normal request and a forward, but things can get quite confusing.  Any help is highly appreciated.

P.S.  The main difference I noticed so far is that the request.forwardURI and request.requestURI differ for a forward, however, the requestURI is in a special format that I currently don't know how to convert to match the forwardURI.

For example for a normal request:

```
request.forwardURI = '/short-url' (as set in URLMappings) or '/controller/action
request.requestURI = '/grails/controller/action.dispatch'
```

For a forward:

```
request.forwardURI = '/short-url' (as set in URLMappings) or '/controller/action'
request.requestURI = '/grails/forwardedController/forwardedAction.dispatch'
```